# How can I count a multivalue field's values in twig?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to count the number of values of unlimited field in twig tempalate I tried

`{{ node.field_mytext.count }}`  => **faced with error**

and  in another try

`{{ content.field_mytext.count }}` => **nothing returned**

(in this method I checked my field is not in disabled field is display manager).

---

**My question is how can I count the number of items of a field in Twig?**

I hope I face with the solutions expect these solutions :D

- add it in preprocess_node
- use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

Comment: did you try {{ content.field_mytext | length }}?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**{{ node.field_mytext.count }} => faced with error**

This does not work, because the method `count` is not allowed in twig policies:

> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigSandboxPolicy.php

**{{ content.field_mytext | length }}?**

This does not work, because `content` is a render array with a lot of additional keys.

**This works: Convert field to array and count**

```
{{ node.field_mytext.getvalue | length }}
```

Comment: you could probably also do it with a foreach loop, but this is cleaner for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way is to get the `['#items']|length`. I do it all the time for counting items for view more instances and when loading sliders.

```
{{ content.field_mytext['#items']|length }}
```

Comment: many thanks to you! But for me it only works if there are multiple items, if its only one i get a debug backtrace ..

Comment: okay i figured out it was because i was using {{ kint(content.field_x['#items']|length) }} to debug which for some reason fails if output is `1`

Answer (score 4):

I've used own Twig filters to support entity fields, with this you can use fields as native arrays:

```
{{ content.field_mytext|length }}
```

or

```
{{ content.field_mytext|first|value }}
```

or

```
{% if content.field_mytext is empty %}
```

---

You can easily add you own Twig filters via a custom module. You can learn more here: [drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules). In short you need to create a module directory, for example `path/to/drupal/modules/custom/common/`, put there `common.info.yml` with module definition and `common.services.yml` with definition of service (see comments in code) and put my code to `/path/to/drupal/modules/custom/common/src/TwigExtension.php`.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\common;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\ComplexDataInterface;

/**
 * A class providing Twig extensions.
 *
 * This provides a Twig extension that registers various Field-API-specific
 * extensions to Twig, overriding empty and array related filters.
 *
 * Don't forget about common.services.yml
 * services:
 *   common.twig.TwigExtension:
 *     class: Drupal\common\TwigExtension
 *     tags:
 *       - { name: twig.extension }
 *
 * Usage (in *.html.twig file):
 *   - check is field empty {% if content.field_foo is empty %}
 *   - get field first value {{ content.field_foo|first|value }}
 */
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTests() {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleTest('empty', [$this, 'twigEmptyField']),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFilters() {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('length', [$this, 'twigLengthFilter'], ['needs_environment' => TRUE]),
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('slice', [$this, 'twigSlice'], ['needs_environment' => TRUE]),
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('first', [$this, 'twigFirst'], ['needs_environment' => TRUE]),
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('last', [$this, 'twigLast'], ['needs_environment' => TRUE]),
      new \Twig_SimpleFilter('value', [$this, 'twigFieldValue']),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Check if value is field item object.
   *
   * @param mixed $value
   *   Mixed Twig variable.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface|mixed
   *   FieldItemListInterface or same value as passed.
   */
  private function checkItems($value) {
    if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['#items']) && $value['#items'] instanceof FieldItemListInterface) {
      return $value['#items'];
    }
    return $value;
  }

  /**
   * Get field item value.
   *
   * @param object $field
   *   Field object.
   *
   * @return array|mixed
   *   List of values or value.
   */
  public function twigFieldValue($field) {
    if ($field instanceof FieldItemInterface) {
      $prop = $field->mainPropertyName();
      $value = $field->getValue();
      return $prop ? $value[$prop] : $value;
    }
    if ($field instanceof FieldItemListInterface) {
      $value = [];
      foreach ($field as $item) {
        $value[] = $this->twigFieldValue($item);
      }
      return $value;
    }
    return '';
  }

  /**
   * Checks if a variable is empty.
   *
   * @see twig_test_empty
   */
  public function twigEmptyField($value) {
    $value = $this->checkItems($value);
    if ($value instanceof ComplexDataInterface) {
      return $value->isEmpty();
    }
    // Return TRUE, because there is no data only cache and weight.
    elseif (!is_object($value) && isset($value['#cache']) && count($value) == 2) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return twig_test_empty($value);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the length of a variable.
   *
   * @param \Twig_Environment $env
   *   Twig environment.
   * @param mixed $item
   *   A variable.
   *
   * @return mixed
   *   The first element of the item.
   *
   * @see twig_length_filter
   */
  public function twigLengthFilter(\Twig_Environment $env, $item) {
    $item = $this->checkItems($item);
    return twig_length_filter($env, $item);
  }

  /**
   * Slices a variable.
   *
   * @param \Twig_Environment $env
   *   Twig environment.
   * @param mixed $item
   *   A variable.
   * @param int $start
   *   Start of the slice.
   * @param int $length
   *   Size of the slice.
   * @param bool $preserveKeys
   *   Whether to preserve key or not (when the input is an array)
   *
   * @return mixed
   *   The first element of the item.
   *
   * @see twig_slice
   */
  public function twigSlice(\Twig_Environment $env, $item, $start, $length = NULL, $preserveKeys = FALSE) {
    $item = $this->checkItems($item);
    return twig_slice($env, $item, $start, $length, $preserveKeys);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the first element of the item.
   *
   * @param \Twig_Environment $env
   *   Twig environment.
   * @param mixed $item
   *   A variable.
   *
   * @return mixed
   *   The first element of the item.
   *
   * @see twig_first
   */
  public function twigFirst(\Twig_Environment $env, $item) {
    $item = $this->checkItems($item);
    return twig_first($env, $item);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the last element of the item.
   *
   * @param \Twig_Environment $env
   *   Twig environment.
   * @param mixed $item
   *   A variable.
   *
   * @return mixed
   *   The first element of the item.
   *
   * @see twig_last
   */
  public function twigLast(\Twig_Environment $env, $item) {
    $item = $this->checkItems($item);
    return twig_last($env, $item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works together with https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value.

```
{% if content.field_paragraphs|field_value|length > 1 %}
  {# Do something. #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [length](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) filter

```
{{ content.field_mytext | length }}
```

Comment: return mistake value !!!, my field is long and I have 4 item in there but return 20 !!!

Comment: this can (depending on circumstances) can return the correct values, but it is an inaccurate answer.